# Folder Organization for Website

Tags: html, apache, mod-rewrite

In my [website](http://www.nextgengaming.org/), I have a home HTML file. Then, when I click on something in the nav, for example Roster, the url changes to `http://www.nextgengaming.org/Roster/roster.html`. How can I stop this? I'm not so worried about the extension, as I can get rid of that later. Here is my file/folder setup that I use when building websites (please note that I have nothing in the html file for 'Roster', because I am focussing on the url right now):

```
Website
  ∟ Home
    ∟ CSS
      HEADER (social icon images)
      home_files (for my image slider)
      IMG (the rest of my images)
      home.html
      home.js

  ∟ Roster
    ∟ roster.html
```

I will fill the roster with pretty much the same things. In my nav I have

`<li><a href="../Roster/roster.html">Roster</a></li>`

so the URL is (as said before) `http://www.nextgengaming.org/Roster/roster.html`, and want to change it to

`http://www.nextgengaming.org/Roster`

**OR**

`http://www.nextgengaming.org/roster.html`

If you need any more information, please comment. Also, I'm not sure if this is the right place to post, but I'll take my chances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The url changes to http://www.nextgengaming.org/Roster/roster.html How can I stop this?

The suggested ways would be to edit **VirtualHost** or **.htaccess** by adding

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [L]
```

Note that `rewrite` module must be enabled (`sudo a2enmod rewrite`). Speaking of `DirectoryIndex` ([documentation here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex)) it searches for

```
index.html index.htm default.htm index.php index.php3 index.phtml index.php5 index.shtml mwindex.phtml
```

And if none of the resources exist and the `Indexes` option is set, the server will generate its own listing of the directory. `Indexes` may cause a security threat (exposing all the files) so use

```
Options -Indexes
```

to avoid that. If following the instructions, the

```
http://www.nextgengaming.org/Roster/roster.html
```

would be rewritten to

```
http://www.nextgengaming.org/Roster/roster
```

To avoid the `Roster/roster` and having just `roster` put the `roster.html` in your `DocumentRoot` probably right next `home.html`.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the default extensions (`index.html` usually), and change the URLs to: `http://www.nextgengaming.org/Home` and `http://www.nextgengaming.org/Roster`

The structure would be:

```
Website
  ∟ Home
    ∟ CSS
      HEADER (social icon images)
      home_files (for my image slider)
      IMG (the rest of my images)
      index.html
      home.js

  ∟ Roster
    ∟ index.html
```

---

If you don't like renaming files like that, a more advanced approch would be to use URL rewriting (using .htaccess, for example).